# How can i bind property values using Kotlin?

Tags: properties, binding, kotlin, classpath

Using java, i can get value of the "spring.datasource.url" key from the application.properties file like this:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SpringJdbcConfig {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;
    private final String URL = "spring.datasource.url";
    String dburl = environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
}
```

Using kotlin, this is not possible like this:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
open class WebController {
    @Autowired
    var env: Environment ? = null
}
```

Environment will not reference to the PropertySource file.
How can i use this in kotlin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For fields that are getting injected kotlin provides the lateinit keyword.

If you want to read a value from your configuration, spring offers you the [@Value annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html)

```
@Value("\${my.property.key}")
lateinit var myValue: String
```

Note that in Java you can use `"${my.property.key}"` as the "path" but since `${}` has a special meaning in kotlin you have to escape the `$` with a `\`